Localization resources with Win10 and Two output file names resolved to the same output path
I have a C# project, which builds fine on Win7. I am now attempting to build the project on Win10, as DigiCert no longer supports Win7 for code signing certificates. The project is complicated enough preventing moving to a newer version of Visual Studio, which I have.
Here is the verbose output from the Win10 build.
18>Target "PrepareResourceNames: (TargetId:473)" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\proj1\Proj1\Proj1.csproj" (target "PrepareResources" depends on it):
18>Done building target "PrepareResourceNames" in project "Proj1.csproj".: (TargetId:473)
18>Target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" skipped. Previously built successfully.
18>Target "SplitResourcesByCulture" skipped. Previously built successfully.
18>Target "BeforeResGen: (TargetId:474)" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\proj1\Proj1\Proj1.csproj" (target "ResGen" depends on it):
18>Done building target "BeforeResGen" in project "Proj1.csproj".: (TargetId:474)
18>Target "CoreResGen: (TargetId:475)" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\proj1\Proj1\Proj1.csproj" (target "ResGen" depends on it):
18>Task "GenerateResource" (TaskId:306)
18>  Launching task "GenerateResource" from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" in an external task host with a runtime of "CLR4" and a process architecture of "x64". (TaskId:306)
18>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2318,5): error MSB3577: Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\x64\Debug\Proj1.FormProj1.resources"
18>Done executing task "GenerateResource" -- FAILED. (TaskId:306)
18>Done building target "CoreResGen" in project "Proj1.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:475)

The key takeaway is this line:
error MSB3577: Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\x64\Debug\Proj1.FormProj1.resources"

I did research here on SO and found quite a few hits for this error.
I do not have duplicate resource names, as I can clean the project and build it with no warnings or errors on Win7. This project does, however, incorporate support for several languages, which I believe are in a subproject that this project includes. I found one of the answers on this one article quite illuminating and making the connection that I might have the same issue.
How can I tell if I do and how can I find the offending language? Basically, I want the problem to disappear, however that happens.
I see these languages in the output directory, however there might be others.
zh-CHT
zh-CHS-800x600
zh-CHS
tr-TR-800x600
tr-TR
ru-RU-800x600
ru-RU
zh-CHT-800x600
ko-KR
ja-JP-800x600
ja-JP
en-US-800x600


I think error is before the duplicate issue.  I think a task is not completing and part of the task is a "move".  So when next item gets compiled the temp filename already exists because the move did not occur.

@jdweng wow! That would make sense. Can you point me to the move operation? That would help me in solving this bug.

Net temp files are in By default, they are created under c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2. 0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files (e.g. for 32-bit . NET 2.0) but you can change it to whatever location you want - particularly to a different partition. In order to do so, you can use the tempDirectory parameter in the  tag in web.

@jdweng How do I find the specific move operation that failed and fix it? You are saying that there might be a permissions problem on the specific folder. That is possible, though hard to imagine.

@jdweng I checked the various .Net temp directories and they are all empty. I have v2.0.50727, v3.-, v3.5, and v4.0.30319. Only the v4 and v3.5 have temp directories. The project uses v4 (I believe).

I would delete the entire obj folder and try build again.
